# Elementary OS is draining my battery

Tags: release-loki, battery

I have a Lenovo Thinkpad T430, and I just installed Elementary OS a week ago.

Since I've been trying it with no charger I've seen how my battery level is reducing almost every three minutes.

I really have no idea of what to do.

Answer (score 3):

Linux in general doesn't have so well implemented battery saving techniques as windows out of the box but that doesn't mean you cannot try to improve things. Take a look at this article which gives some pointers how to maximize your laptop battery https://www.howtogeek.com/55185/how-to-maximize-the-battery-life-on-your-linux-laptop/ in my case (I have Lenovo Thinkpad X230) installing tlp helped the most so I recommend you to make youself familiar with http://linrunner.de/en/tlp/docs/tlp-linux-advanced-power-management.html there are specific tlp modules created especially for Thinkpads (tp-smapi-dkms and acpi-call-dkms). I hope this helps :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try "powertop" in terminal and check what is eating your battery.